# how to Convert multidimensional array into single array

Tags: php

I have a dynamic, multi-dimensional array as shown below:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 63 [1] => 60 [2] => 67 [3] => 58 [4] => 35 [5] => 47 [6] => 30 [7] => 47 [8] => 61 [9] => 63 [10] => 56 [11] => 56 [12] => 44 [13] => 38 [14] => 36 [15] => 45 [16] => 39 [17] => 55 [18] => 60 [19] => 45 [20] => 37 [21] => 45 [22] => 63 [23] => 62 [24] => 50 [25] => 47 [26] => 46 [27] => 37 [28] => 69 [29] => 35 [30] => 33 [31] => 65 [32] => 63 [33] => 50 [34] => 69 [35] => 43 [36] => 65 [37] => 64 [38] => 45 [39] => 65 [40] => 43 [41] => 30 [42] => 51 [43] => 28 [44] => 33 [45] => 53 [46] => 67 [47] => 28 [48] => 47 [49] => 42 [50] => 49 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 30 [2] => 27 [3] => 29 [4] => 29 [5] => 29 [6] => 27 [7] => 28 [8] => 30 [9] => 29 [10] => 29 [11] => 29 [12] => 29 [13] => 28 [14] => 30 [15] => 29 [16] => 29 [17] => 28 [18] => 30 [19] => 27 [20] => 28 [21] => 27 [22] => 29 [23] => 30 [24] => 30 [25] => 28 [26] => 30 [27] => 29 [28] => 30 [29] => 27 [30] => 27 [31] => 27 [32] => 29 [33] => 29 [34] => 30 [35] => 28 [36] => 29 [37] => 29 [38] => 28 [39] => 30 [40] => 28 [41] => 28 [42] => 28 [43] => 28 [44] => 30 [45] => 27 [46] => 28 [47] => 27 [48] => 30 [49] => 27 [50] => 29 ) )
```

I want to convert it to this output array:

```
Array (
    [0] => 63,30
    .....
    [50] => 49,29
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you the answer you want. It finds the keys of the first element of the array using [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) then uses [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to fetch the values for that key for each entry in the array. The result from `array_column` is [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)'d to give the desired value for the new array:

```
$newarray = array();
$keys = array_keys(array_values($array)[0]);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $newarray[$key] = implode(',', array_column($array, $key));
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => 63,30
    [1] => 60,30
    [2] => 67,27
    [3] => 58,29
    ...
    [50] => 49,29 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TpOYV)